# WP: How to get the id of certain post by title

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to get the **id** of a post by **title**.
The script below shows the content of a post by id.

```
  $content_post = get_post($postID);
  $content = $content_post->post_content;

  return apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

My goal is to use the **title** as parameter in order to get the related id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check this code?

```
$page = get_page_by_title(' Your page title '); // enter your page title

$pageID = $page->ID; 

echo $pageID;
```

for more information you can refer this link [get_page_by_title](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_page_by_title](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title). You may have more than one post with the same name so that may return more than one entry.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The names of the posts are unique. I tried this but it does not work: $page = get_page_by_title('Title.one');
         $pageID =  $page->ID;

Comment: Try getting a post that you know exists (by id) and then get_page_by_title() with that post title.

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

Retrieves a post given its title. If more than one post uses the same title, the post with the smallest ID will be returned.

Because this function uses the MySQL '=' comparison the $page_title will usually be matched as case insensitive with default collating.
Usage

```
<?php 
 get_page_by_title( $page_title, $output, $post_type );
?>
```

**Parameters**

```
$page_title
(string) (required) Page title
Default: None 

 $output
 (string) (optional) Output type. OBJECT, ARRAY_N, or ARRAY_A.
 Default: OBJECT 

$post_type
(string) (optional) Post type like 'page', 'post', 'product' etc.
Default: page
```

**Return Values**

```
(mixed) 
OBJECT, ARRAY_N, or ARRAY_A.
```

NULL when no posts found.

Check it out on **[wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title)**.

Another way of doing this is as follows.

**The problem**

The function converts a post / page name to a post /page ID.

```
function get_id_by_post_name($post_name)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = '".$post_name."'");
    return $id;
}
```

**Function call**

Call the function somewhere in your theme.

```
<?php echo get_id_by_post_name('my-post-name'); ?>
```